# Error: [Vue warn]: Invalid handler for event "click": got undefined

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, tsx, vue-mixin

I'm using Vue 2 (class syntax) and Typescript (TSX syntax) and I know this question has been asked a few times but none of the answers I've seen have applied to my own situation.

I've created an object array and I'm outputting these objects as custom HTML elements, let's call them `Chips`. A `Chip` takes the property '`selected`' as a `boolean`.

The array is called `registerCategory` and each object in the array has a `name` (basically just its text) and a `boolean` i called `is_selected` whose default is `false`.

Alright, here's how I've outputted my Array

```
  {this.registerCategory.map((field, index) => (
    <ZChip
    position={'start'}
    id = {'field-' + index}
    value={field}
    selected={this.registerCategory[index].is_selected}
    onClick={this.onCategorySelect(index)}
    >
      {this.$t(this.registerCategory[index].name)}
    </ZChip>
  ))}
```

This outputs all the elements wonderfully. My issue now is getting them to be selected on click.

I've made this function in a separate `registration.mixin.ts` file (which is also the same place the array is defined in a `computed` block):

```
  methods: {
    onCategorySelect(index: number): void {
      this.registerCategory[index].is_selected = true;
    },
}
```

This should change the `is_select` as only the selected element's selected `boolean`. However, that gave me:

> [Vue warn]: Invalid handler for event "click": got undefined

Any help, solution, or work-around is greatly appreciated. Thanks. :)

Comment: Looks like the function is executed immediately, and you get either `:onClick=undefined` (leading to an invalid handler error) or `:onClick="true"` (leading to handler.apply is not a function). Just a guess though

Comment: @MoritzRingler it has been seeming like it’s executed immediately rather than on click. should I try making the function async? But why do you think it isn’t being executed ONLY on click in the first place?

Comment: Making the function async would not change how it is invoked here. My guess is it should be something `onClick={'onCategorySelect(' + index + ')'}` but this might be as stupid as it looks, I am not familiar with TSX

Comment: @MoritzRingler haha no problem but what is it you're trying to achieve with that passing? as in, why pass white spaces/what would it look like on regular vue & js syntax? I'll try applying it to TSX syntax

Comment: Usually, you would pass in a string `onCategorySelect(index)` and the Vue template compiler figures out that `onCategorySelect` is a method on the component and `index` a variable in the current scope. Then it creates a callback from that for the click event.

Comment: @MoritzRingler Ah, no with TSX it usually works with the syntax I used. I use `onClick` all the time the way I have in the question, the problem only happens with this damn `ZChip` and it's selected `boolean`. Either way, I tried passing it as a string your way, it made no difference anyway. Thank you though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you figure it out already? I can't test it, but I am pretty sure this works, it matches how indexes are handled in React (afaik):

```
  methods: {
    onCategorySelect(index: number): void {
      () => this.registerCategory[index].is_selected = true;
    },
  }
```

Comment: I did figure it out, but you're basically right! I did the arrow function expression within `onClick` though, as the other part of the issue was the fact I had put the Array in a `computed` block and computed arrays can't be mutated. I've described it in detail in my own answer if you're curious but choosing yours as correct because it also works and has the same idea and you went out of your way to help so thanks! :')

Answer (score 1):

Answering my question in depth in case anyone needs it -- with the help of my supervisor, I've figured out that 2 things were a problem in my code:

1. I've dumbly put the array in `computed` object (because -- correct me if I'm wrong -- as far as I know Arrays with custom types can't be defined in the `data` object, and anything in a `computed` block can't be mutated. So I moved the array to the same class the rest of my code was (where the `ZChip` elements are). I'm sure there is some better place to put the Array initialization other than where I put it but oh well.
2. In `onClick`, I had to use `arrow function` expression to call the function. This is how the code's been changed:

   ```
     {this.registerCategory.map((field, index) => (
       <ZidChip
       position="start"
       id = {'field-' + index}
       value={field}
       selected={this.registerCategory[index].is_selected}
       onClick={() => this.onCategorySelect(index)}
       >
         {this.$t(this.registerCategory[index].name)}
       </ZidChip>
     ))}
   ```

Where `onCategorySelect` looks like:

```
  private onCategorySelect(index: number): void {
    this.registerCategory[index].is_selected = !this.registerCategory[index].is_selected;
  }
```